# python use variable inside command.replace

Tags: python

This is driving me crazy.  I have a string like this:

```
Sheridan School III
```

In a list like this:

```
Sheridan School III
Lake Bluff Elementary II
Barrington IV
```

I'd like to make the trailing portion into a variable `homeseries`

And make the portion that precedes that into variable `homeclub`

When I split the string I can get the series, no problem, as in below.

But I cannot use that series inside the `.replace` string, where I'd like to just use it to get rid of the last part of the original string. How do I use a variable inside .replace?  Python throws an error and I'm sure there is a simple way to reference this as a variable.

```
homeclubfull = "Sheridan School III"
homeclublist = homeclubfull.split(" ")
homeseries = homeclublist[-1:]    # this should return "III"
homeclub=homeclubfull.replace(homeseries,'')
print homeclub, home series
```

error thrown:

```
import.py:51: TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split from the end with the [`str.rsplit()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) and a limit:

```
homeclub, homeseries = homeclubfull.rsplit(None, 1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> homeclubfull = "Sheridan School III"
>>> homeclub, homeseries = homeclubfull.rsplit(None, 1)
>>> homeclub
'Sheridan School'
>>> homeseries
'III'
```

The error you get because you were trying to pass a *list* to `.replace()`, not a string; you wanted this instead:

```
homeseries = homeclublist[-1]   # Note, no :
```

You were *slicing* the list, not selecting one element. Slicing results in a list, always:

```
>>> homeclubfull.split()[-1:]
['III']
>>> homeclubfull.split()[-1]
'III'
```

Comment: Not only did you fix it (thanks) you educated me (thanks ^2)- you're fantastic, Martijn!!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem would be solved if instead of `homeclublist[-1:]` you used `homeclublist[-1]` because the first one returns a list (it leaves a trailing space that you can strip).

You could also do this without replace; by slicing the part of the list that you want as opposed to the part that you don't want and then replace:

```
homeclubfull = "Sheridan School III"
homeclublist = homeclubfull.split()
homeseries = ' '.join(homeclublist[:-1])
print(homeseries)
```

Comment: Thanks, Jurgenreza -- appreciate the clarification!!